# Parsing HTML with TFHpple on iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, tfhpple

I am working on an iOS project and my goal is to create a "pretty" app version of a specific website.  To do this, I'm parsing all the data from said website with TFHpple for use in my app.

This website has a store, so my goal was to read the webpage with the products, then display them all in a table view and what not.  However, the website doesn't display all the products on the specific page at once.

It splits up the products across 3 pages inside the one website page so you have to click the "next page" button on the website, and that runs some javascript code and adds the "?foo" part to make the URL in the browser be "http://www.domain.com/page?foo".  I read up that this "?foo" is a query string, however I don't know how I would trigger this in my Objective-C code from the base "http://www.domain.com/page" page.

So simply,  I can't grab all the items I would like to with TFHpple because some are not in the HTML until the correct query string is used.

I'm not really sure if I am explaining my predicament very clearly, but if anyone has any info that I could use I would appreciate it immensely!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project. I think your problem has nothing to do with TFHpple. TFHpple only handles HTML parsing rather than data downloading from server. My approach is like this:

```
NSInteger currentPageIndex=1;
NSString *dataUrlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/page?index=%d",currentPageIndex];
```

1. Detecting tableView's scrolling event, if it reaches the end of the tableView, then load next page data from server;
2. Parse the new page's HTML data from server, append data to tableView's datasource and reload the tableView.

Comment: Thank you very much.  You spurred some ideas in my head.  I don't really want to hardcode all of the query string values, since I would like my table view controller to work with multiple webpages.

I have found that I can search for the "Add_Search_Param" in the HTML code and I should be able to find all the different query's I can use.